# Assigning an OSM originated tag to a Shapefile field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, openstreetmap, geotag

I am using QGIS to do some basic data processing.

I have a shapefile (originated from OSM data) that has a number of fields. One of those fields (tags) contains a bunch of tag data.

Example of a "tags" field record below:

`"name"=>"Felice Island"`, `"place"=>"island"`, `"osm_uid"=>"14512"`, `"osm_user"=>"DENelson83"`, `"way_area"=>"1.94426e-05"`, `"osm_version"=>"1"`, `"osm_changeset"=>"59732201"`, `"osm_timestamp"=>"2018-06-11T08:10:52Z"`

What I want to do is create a brand new field that contains just the values of the `"way_area"` tags.

I've been trying to set this up using the QGIS attribute table but can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `other_tags` field is an HStore type.

In **QGIS 3.4**, you can populate your new field with the expression below:

```
map_get( hstore_to_map(  "other_tags" ), 'way_area' )
```

or another syntax in **QGIS 3.6**

```
hstore_to_map("other_tags")['way_area']
```

The `hstore_to_map` expression taks an HStore field and returns a dictionary with key/value.

In **QGIS 3.6** (February 2019), you can use the `Explode HStore Field` algorithm and give the `way_area` parameter. Without specifying a list of field, the algorithm will create one new field for each key in your HStore field.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

`replace( array_get( regexp_matches("your field name",'"way_area"=>"([^,]*)') ,0) ,'"','')`

in the field calculator? Which will do it with a regex.

Not exactly elegant, but gets the job done as I don't think QGIS has support for JSON in fields.

Comment: I tried this in the field calculator but the syntax did not work. A few manual replace's might do the trick but am not sure how to get a wildcard replace to work for the whole field. If I can whittle down the following (example record):     "name"=>"Riley Island", "place"=>"island", "osm_uid"=>"14512", "osm_user"=>"DENelson83", "way_area"=>"5.6119e-06", "osm_version"=>"1", "osm_changeset"=>"59732201", "osm_timestamp"=>"2018-06-11T08:10:57Z" to     "way_area"=>"5.6119e-06"      then I think I can make this work.

Comment: what did you try? what was the result?

Comment: If I create a dataset with a field the same as that, and run the function above in field calculator on that field, I get the number 5.6119e-06. If you need it as text "way_area"=>.... then you probably need to modify your question

Comment: When I try this I get an invalid expression error: (Parser Error:
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting COMMA or ')'
Eval Error: No root node! Parsing failed? Although I've found another way to do this, it would be nice to get this to work as it would be much more elegant. The floating point number BTW is exactly what I need.

Comment: which version of QGIS are you using? If not on 3, maybe try that?

Comment: Using v2.18.7. Will upgrade to 3 and see if that makes a difference.